# Splitting content of file and make it in order

Tags: bash, awk, sed, grep, cut

I have a file like so:

```
{A{AAA} B{BBB} test {CCC CCC
}}
{E{EEE} F{FFF} test {GGG GGG
}}
{H{HHH} I{III} test {JJJ -JJJ
}}
{K{KKK} L{LLL} test {MMM 
}}
```

## Updated

I want to use linux commands in order to have the following output:

```
AAA:BBB:CCC CCC
EEE:FFF:GGG GGG
HHH:III:JJJ -JJJ
KKK:LLL:MMM
```

Comment: I have tried sth with awk but this is not what I want at all

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using gnu-awk you can do this:

```
awk -v RS='}}' -v FPAT='{[^{}]+(}|\n)' -v OFS=':' '{for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) {
              gsub(/[{}]|\n/, "", $i); printf "%s%s", $i, (i<NF)?OFS:ORS}}' file
AAA:BBB:CCC CCC
EEE:FFF:GGG GGG
HHH:III:JJJ -JJJ
KKK:LLL:MMM
```

- `-v RS='}}'` will break each record using `}}` text
- `-v FPAT='{[^{}]+(}|\n)'` will split field using given regex. Regex matches each field that starts with `{` and matches anything but `{ and }` followed by `}` or a newline.
- `-v OFS=':'` sets output field separator as `:`
- `gsub(/[{}]|\n/, "", $i)` removes `{` or `}` or newline from each field

**Shorter command** (thanks to JoseRicardo):

```
awk -v RS='}}' -v FPAT='{[^{}]+(}|\n)' -v OFS=':' '{$1=$1} gsub(/[{}]|\n/, "")' file
```

or even this:

```
awk -v FPAT='{[^{}]{2,}' -v OFS=':' '{$1=$1} gsub(/[{}]/, "")' file
```

Comment: Yes that is even shorter. Let me update the answer with that as well.

Answer (score 1):

Perl solution

```
perl -nwe 'print join ":", /{([^{}]{2,})/g' file
```

The regular expression extracts groups of 2 or more non-curlies following a curlie, they are then printed separated with colons.

Answer (score 1):

for this specific format

```
sed -n 's/...//;s/}[^{]*//g;s/{/:/gp' YourFile
```